# Very slow NOT EXISTS query issue

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anyone tell me if there are any obvious issues as to why the following query is taking 1.3seconds to complete?

Is there a way I can speed this query up?

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT jud.rel_id) AS count_result
    FROM exp_judging AS jud
    LEFT JOIN exp_submissions AS sub ON jud.rel_id = sub.id 
    WHERE (jud.judge_id != 781 OR jud.judge_id IS NULL)
    AND jud.pre = 1
    AND sub.member_group = 5
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT sub2.entry_id 
                            FROM exp_judging AS jud2
                    LEFT JOIN exp_submissions AS sub2 ON jud2.rel_id = sub2.id 
                    WHERE (jud2.judge_id = 781)
                    AND jud2.pre = 1
                    AND sub2.member_group = 5
                    AND jud2.rel_id = jud.rel_id)
```

Comment: Don't use `LEFT JOIN` if you're using something in that table in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @Barmar Can you suggest what I should be using?

Comment: @barmar could you explain?

Comment: Please include related table schema, EXPLAIN result, and size of result set. Besides that, this is an expensive query with the `!=` and `OR`, and correlated subquery.

Comment: What is the Primary Key on the exp_judging table?

Comment: @ccdavies The reason to use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` is because you want the result to include rows in the first table with no match in the second table. But if your `WHERE` clause tests columns in the second table (other than `col IS NULL`), rows with no matches will be excluded by that, so there's no reason to use the more expensive `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: @Barmar, MySQL 5+ [automatically optimizes outer join to inner join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/outer-join-simplification.html).

Comment: I had a query using MySQL 5.3 that was significantly slower when it used an outer join than when I rewrote it to use an inner join.

Comment: Oh, I see -- it does that optimization when it sees that the `WHERE` clause would filter out null rows. The query I had didn't have that.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this logic?  There might be an easier way to express it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have re-written the whole query to 1) first, select exp_judging.rel_id's that do not have a row with judge_id=781, and 2) then, for these rel_id's the count is obtained from the exp_judging table.

**EDIT**:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT jud0.rel_id)
FROM
    exp_judging AS jud0
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT 
            jud.rel_id as rel_id,
            SUM(
                CASE jud.judge_id
                    WHEN 781 THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                END) sum_judge_id
        FROM 
            exp_judging AS jud
            INNER JOIN exp_submissions AS sub
                ON jud.rel_id = sub.id 
        WHERE 
            jud.pre = 1
            AND sub.member_group = 5
        GROUP BY 
            jud.rel_id) judge_id_sums
        ON jud0.rel_id = judge_id_sums.rel_id 
WHERE 
    judge_id_sums.sum_judge_id = 0;
```

The inner join `exp_judging` and `exp_submissions` will count `jud.rel_id` only if `jud2.rel_id` exists in `exp_submissions` (as `sub2.id`). However, if you do want to count all `jud.rel_id` (even if it does not exist in `exp_submissions`), then `LEFT JOIN` may be used.

Comment: Thank you! I have tried this, and it doesn't seem to be speeding the query up. On the initial query, if I remove the AND NOT EXISTS line, its almost instant. Can you suggest an option instead of that line?

Comment: @ccdavies I have re-written the query completely. First, the presence of judge_id = 781 is detected. Then, these rows are filtered OUT (judge_id_sums.sum_judge_id = 0) when counting distinct rel_id. The join with exp_submissions does not have to be repeated, because it is already done in the inline view.

Comment: @ccdavies You're welcome!! I have learnt something new in the process, too!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to count the distinct `jud.rel_id` subject to some conditions:

1. `jud.pre = 1`
2. `sub.member_group = 5`
3. The group does not contain judge 781

Answering some question like "How many "pre" judges in group 5 have never had a submission with judge 781?".  If so, there might be an easier way to write the query.

In any case, your query, rewritten so I can read it is:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT jud.rel_id) AS count_result
FROM exp_judging jud LEFT JOIN
     exp_submissions sub
     ON jud.rel_id = sub.id 
WHERE (jud.judge_id != 781 OR jud.judge_id IS NULL) AND
      jud.pre = 1 AND
      sub.member_group = 5 AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT sub2.entry_id 
                  FROM exp_judging jud2 LEFT JOIN
                       exp_submissions sub2
                       ON jud2.rel_id = sub2.id 
                  WHERE jud2.judge_id = 781 AND
                        jud2.pre = 1 AND
                        sub2.member_group = 5 AND
                        jud2.rel_id = jud.rel_id
                 )
```

You want to use indexes to speed the query.  My best guess at indexes for this query are:

```
exp_judging(judge_id, pre, rel_id)
exp_submissions(id, member_group)
```